# lost session in php script from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using Cakephp, on InfoController->index() I'm setting

```
$_SESSION['dir'] = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/../webroot";
```

Inside the view of index, there's a button that calls an ajax code

```
function MakeAjax(option)
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url:"../app/webroot/directories.php",
        dataType:'html',


data:{newdir: option},
    success:function(result)
    {
        console.log(result);
    }

    });
}
```

and this is directories.php

```
$value = $_POST['newdir'];

if(strcmp($value,'..') == 0)
{
preg_match('/\/[^\/]+$/',$_SESSION['dir'],$hello); // obtiene /A de X/X/X/A
...more code....
```

I already tried using session_start, but for some reason the variable dir in session is lost.
I get unknown variable _SESSION, and if I set session_start, then I get unknown variable dir...

any ideas?

Comment: show more php code please

Comment: how did you try `session_start`? it is a language construct called with `session_start();` it needs to be run in **both** php files before accessing `$_SESSION`

Comment: I used session_start() at the start of directories.php

Comment: I can't use it on the controller because it's already started before.

Comment: if its already started the writing to the session should not be a problem try `session_id() || session_start();` instead of `session_start();` then you dont have to be afraid of trying to start the session twice because it will only if there is no session already

Comment: Ok, but for some reason, when I check if there's a session initiated in directories.php, the result is none (no session)

Comment: I couldn't solve this problem using session. I had to save the information in a hidden field and then retrieved it from javascript (it's a mess)....